# How to initialize jQuery widget in Handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, jquery, handlebars.js, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a test.hbs file with a jQuery accordion:

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
  <h3>Section 2</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Sed non urna. Donec et ante. Phasellus eu ligula. Vestibulum sit amet
    purus. Vivamus hendrerit, dolor at aliquet laoreet, mauris turpis porttitor
    velit, faucibus interdum tellus libero ac justo. Vivamus non quam. In
    suscipit faucibus urna.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I initialize this accordion within the test.hbs file?

```
  $(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
  });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since handlebars produces strings instead of DOM elements this is a bit tricky. There are some solutions for extending handlebars into a DOM-based templating engine (see the deprecated DOMBars project, for example).

I've created a handlebars helper that can get a hold of the DOM element using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for detecting when the relevant piece of html gets added. ([Browser support](http://caniuse.com/#feat=mutationobserver) info, see [webcomponents-lite](http://webcomponents.org/polyfills/) for a polyfill).

Here's the utility in [GitHub](https://github.com/ekuusela/post-render-bars) and a [**demo**](http://ekuusela.github.io/post-render-bars/example/withjquery.html).

An example template:

```
<p>Here is a plugin:</p>
{{#jqinit 'accordion'}}
<div>
    <h3>Section 1</h3>
    <div><p>Mauris mauris ante...</p></div>
    <h3>Section 2</h3>
    <div><p>Sed non urna...</p></div>
</div>
{{/jqinit}}
```

Brief description for the relevant code:

[watch.js](https://github.com/ekuusela/post-render-bars/blob/master/watch.js) defines a function `forHtml(html, callback)` which triggers a callback when the given html is encountered in the DOM. It modifies the html to temporarily have a class that makes it unique.

[jQueryHelpers.js](https://github.com/ekuusela/post-render-bars/blob/master/jQueryHelpers.js) defines the helper `jqinit`, which uses the `watch.forHtml` function to watch for the block defined by the helper and then calls a function on the DOM element. The helper takes the function name as a first parameter and optionally a JSON object that gets parsed and passed as an argument to the function.